# Append non numeric key-values to an array

Tags: php

Trying to return a DB resultset as an array in my DAO:

I want to append string key-values to the array `$retval` in the below code. However, the array keeps getting overwritten each iteration instead of being appended to.

So at the end of the loop, I end up with 1 key-value instead of n pairs (n rows retrieved from the database). What am I doing wrong?

```
$retval = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    foreach($columns as $var) {
        $retval[$var]=$row[$var];
    }

}
var_dump($retval);
```

`$retval` ends up as `["name"=>"Japan","capital"=>"Tokyo"]` instead of the expected `["name"=>"Korea","capital"=>"Seoul"...."Japan"=>"Tokyo"]` where columns are name and capital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are overwriting the same value (column name here.)  Something like:

```
$retval['a'] = 1;
$retval['a'] = 2;
// ...
```

Instead use:

```
$retval[] = $row[$var];
```

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to see what your columns are, but shouldn't it be:

```
$retval = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  $retval[ $row['country'] ] = $row['capital'];

}
```

Comment: Sorry my example was incorrect. Had to make an edit. Basically I am trying to convert the DB rows into an array where key is column name and value is column value, but the last row is getting overwritten.

Comment: $row is already an associative array with key=>value entries, for the table _row_ - are you after an array of hashes (associative arrays)?

For example:

$row[0] = array( 'name' => 'Japan', 'capital' => 'Tokyo' ..);
$row[1] = array( 'name' => 'Korea', 'capital' => 'Seoul' ..);

If so, you want:

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $retval[] = $row;
    }